# Unable to render image inside D3 force directed graph

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I have a force directed graph of countries sharing borders. I wanted to display a flag of the country on each node. I can see the image in the generated HTML and also can see it taking the space in the window but it is not visible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="flags/flags.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <title>National Contiguity Visualization</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="details">National Contiguity</div>
  <svg class="plot"></svg>
  <div class="tooltip hidden"></div>
  <svg width="100" height="100">
      <foreignobject class="node" >

          <img class="flag flag-cz" alt="Czech Republic" src="flags/blank.png"/>                    
      </foreignobject>
  </svg>

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the JS file.

```
const apiUrl = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DealPete/forceDirected/master/countries.json';
const tooltip = document.getElementsByClassName('tooltip')[0];

const dragstarted = d => {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

const dragged = d => {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

const dragended = d => {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}

const plot = (data) => {
  data.nodes = data.nodes.map((d, index) => {
    d['id'] = index;
    return d;
  });
  const margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 10,
    left: 100
  };
  const width = Math.max((((window.innerWidth / 100) * 80) - margin.right - margin.left), 700);
  const height = ((window.innerHeight / 100) * 80) - margin.bottom - margin.top;
  const svg = d3.select('svg')
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right + 100)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom + 100)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform',
      `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

  const simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force('link', d3.forceLink().id(function (d) { return d.id; }).distance(100).strength(1))
    .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody())
    .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

  const dragstarted = d => {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  }

  const dragged = d => {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
  }

  const dragended = d => {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  }

  const ticked = () => {
    link
      .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
      .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
      .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
      .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);

    node
      .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x = Math.max(5, Math.min(width - 5, d.x)); })
      .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y = Math.max(5, Math.min(height - 5, d.y)); });
  }

  const link = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'links')
    .selectAll('line')
    .data(data.links)
    .enter().append('line')
    .attr('stroke-width', function (d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  const node = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'nodes')
    .selectAll('.flag')
    .data(data.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append('foreignobject')
    .append('img')
    .attr('src', 'flags/blank.png')
    .attr('class', d => `flag flag-cz`)
    .attr('width', '5px')
    .attr('height', '5px')
    .attr("x", -8)
    .attr("y", -8)
    .call(d3.drag()
      .on('start', dragstarted)
      .on('drag', dragged)
      .on('end', dragended));

  node.append("title")
    .text(function (d) { return d.country; })
    .exit();

  simulation
    .nodes(data.nodes)
    .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
    .links(data.links);

}

const fetchData = () => {
  return fetch(apiUrl)
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    });
};

const fetchAndPlot = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetchData();
    console.log(response);
    plot(response);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}

fetchAndPlot();
```

Tried the svg image element and the foreignobject method. The one written directly in HTML is rendered properly. Unable to figure out the issue with this for the past 3/4 days.

Repo: [National Contiguity Visualization](https://github.com/dhanushuUzumaki/national-contiguity-visualization/tree/develop)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Don't use `foreingObject`. 2. If you still want to use it, set the width and height: `.attr("width", whatever).attr("height", whatever)`.

Comment: Try adding width and heigh attributes to the foreignObject tag, or just use a SVG <image> tag instead.

Comment: Width and height of foreignObject? But I am not sure how that would solve the rendering issue. I tried the svg image element but the same thing happens in that too... the image is not being rendered..

Comment: @DhanushuUzumaki Imagine that you want to render a rectangle. Can you do it without setting the width and height?

Comment: They are mandatory attributes in SVG 1.1 the SVG 1.1 spec says if you omit them, render nothing. SVG 2 changes this but only Chrome has implemented that I think.

Comment: I tried setting width and height.. but still not rendering..

Comment: maybe d3 wants foreignObject to be written correctly i.e. with a capital O

Comment: I updated my code to ```.append('foreignObject')
    .attr('width', '5px')
    .attr('height', '5px')
    .append('img')
    .attr('src', 'flags/blank.png')
    .attr('class', d => `flag flag-cz`)
    .attr('width', '5px')
    .attr('height', '5px')``` But this is also not working. Infact on this one.. I can't even focus to them through dev tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you need width and height attributes on foreignObject tags
- foreignObject is spelled with a capital O, although HTML markup is not case sensitive, DOM creation of elements and therefore d3 is case sensitive.
- d3 wants HTML tags to be prefixed by xhtml:

Since you didn't provide a flag, I've used an example flag. Note that all your nodes are positioned one on top of the other at the moment, but I guess that's another question if you can't solve that.

```js
const apiUrl = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DealPete/forceDirected/master/countries.json';
const tooltip = document.getElementsByClassName('tooltip')[0];

const dragstarted = d => {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

const dragged = d => {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

const dragended = d => {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}

const plot = (data) => {
  data.nodes = data.nodes.map((d, index) => {
    d['id'] = index;
    return d;
  });
  const margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 10,
    left: 100
  };
  const width = Math.max((((window.innerWidth / 100) * 80) - margin.right - margin.left), 700);
  const height = ((window.innerHeight / 100) * 80) - margin.bottom - margin.top;
  const svg = d3.select('svg')
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right + 100)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom + 100)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform',
      `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

  const simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force('link', d3.forceLink().id(function (d) { return d.id; }).distance(100).strength(1))
    .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody())
    .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

  const dragstarted = d => {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  }

  const dragged = d => {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
  }

  const dragended = d => {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  }

  const ticked = () => {
    link
      .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
      .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
      .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
      .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);

    node
      .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x = Math.max(5, Math.min(width - 5, d.x)); })
      .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y = Math.max(5, Math.min(height - 5, d.y)); });
  }

  const link = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'links')
    .selectAll('line')
    .data(data.links)
    .enter().append('line')
    .attr('stroke-width', function (d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  const node = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'nodes')
    .selectAll('.flag')
    .data(data.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append('foreignObject')
    .attr('width', '100')
    .attr('height', '100')
    .append('xhtml:img')
    .attr('src', 'https://flaglane.com/download/british-flag/british-flag-small.gif')
    .attr('class', d => `flag flag-cz`)
    .call(d3.drag()
      .on('start', dragstarted)
      .on('drag', dragged)
      .on('end', dragended));

  node.append("title")
    .text(function (d) { return d.country; })
    .exit();

  simulation
    .nodes(data.nodes)
    .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
    .links(data.links);

}

const fetchData = () => {
  return fetch(apiUrl)
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    });
};

const fetchAndPlot = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetchData();
    plot(response);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}

fetchAndPlot();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="flags/flags.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <title>National Contiguity Visualization</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="details">National Contiguity</div>
  <svg class="plot"></svg>
  <div class="tooltip hidden"></div>

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I reckon the issue of `foreignObject` being case sensitive is not due to D3, since D3 is render agnostic. Correct me if I'm wrong, but `foreignObject` should have capital O because it is an SVG element and XML (unlike HTML) is case sensitive.

Comment: SVG when embedded in HTML as markup is case insensitive. When you create it via the DOM it's case sensitive whether it's XML or HTML so it's really the DOM rather than d3 I suppose. I've expanded the explanation.

Comment: Indeed. If you look at the source code for D3 `append()` method you'll see that it uses `document.createElementNS`... so, that explains why it is case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks, @Robert and Gerardo Now the images are properly rendered. If I can ask for one more help, the x and y coordinates are applied to the last appended element (img in this case).. is there a way to apply it to foreignObject?

Comment: @DhanushuUzumaki This is easy to fix. However, don't ask new questions in the comments: instead of that, post a *new question*.

Comment: @Gerard Posted a new question regarding this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49475042/d3-x-and-y-coordinates-applied-to-last-appened-element-instead-of-the-group